# Como posso modificar uma variável de escopo local dentro de uma função?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, typescript

Basicamente quero que a função abaixo retorne um boolean para que eu saiba se a transação ocorreu com sucesso ou não :

```
     public persistirPagamento = async (agencia: string, banco: string, conta: string, saldo: number, valorConta: number, idTransacao: string): Promise<boolean> => {

    var resultadoTransacao: boolean = true
    var transaction = new mssql.Transaction(this.connection)

    await transaction.begin(mssql.ISOLATION_LEVEL.READ_COMMITTED, async (err) => {

        if (err != undefined) {
            console.error(err)
            console.error("Erro no inicio da transação")
            resultadoTransacao = err
            return
        }

        var request = new mssql.Request(transaction)

        const updateResult = await this.updateAccount(agencia, banco, conta, saldo, request);

        if (updateResult != true) {
            console.error("Erro no update de valores, rollback")
            transaction.rollback()
            resultadoTransacao = false// Cancela resto da operação
            return
        }


        const insertMovtoResult = await this.insertMovto(agencia, banco, conta, valorConta, request, idTransacao);

        if (insertMovtoResult != true) {
            console.error("Erro ao realizar inserção de movto, iniciando rollback...")
            transaction.rollback()
            resultadoTransacao = false
            console.log("Result dentro do inserir movto", resultadoTransacao)
            return
        }

        const resutl  = await transaction.commit()
        console.log("RESULTADO GERAL DDDD - ", resutl)

    })
    console.log(resultadoTransacao)
    return resultadoTransacao
}
```

Mas apesar das tentativas o valor de `resultadoTransacao` não é alterado dentro da função passada por parâmetro no `transaction.begin` o que noto é que se coloco comentários logo antes de `return resultadoTransacao` que é escrito no final da função ele é impresso antes dos comentários presentes dentro da função do `transaction.begin`

Como posso "ordenar" a execução das funções para que minha variável local seja setada corretamente ?

Comment: O problema não é que a variável não está sendo alterada. Ela está sim, mas o método `transaction.begin` é assíncrono, então a função passa para o retorno direto antes do valor ter sido alterada. Tenta colocar um `await` antes de `transaction.begin`, dessa forma deve aguardar até o processamento ter sido concluído

Comment: @PauloSouza já tentei e não funcionou :/ o estado da variável sempre se mantém o da inicialização.

Comment: Observando a documentação do `mssql` perceba que a função `commit` pode retornar uma promise se nenhum callback for passado: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#commit-callback. Assim, deve ser possível utilizar um bloco try/catch + await para fazer a verificação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não bastaria retornar o booleano pelo seu método?

Você pode usar a sintaxe comum da promise (sem async/await) para trabalhar com retornos dentro de callbacks

```
public persistirPagamento = (agencia: string, banco: string, conta: string, saldo: number, valorConta: number, idTransacao: string): Promise<boolean> => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var transaction = new mssql.Transaction(this.connection)

    transaction.begin(mssql.ISOLATION_LEVEL.READ_COMMITTED, async (err) => {

        if (err != undefined) {
            console.error(err)
            console.error("Erro no inicio da transação")
            resolve(false);
            return
        }

        var request = new mssql.Request(transaction)

        const updateResult = await this.updateAccount(agencia, banco, conta, saldo, request);

        if (updateResult != true) {
            console.error("Erro no update de valores, rollback")
            transaction.rollback()
            resolve(false)
            return // Cancela resto da operação
        }


        const insertMovtoResult = await this.insertMovto(agencia, banco, conta, valorConta, request, idTransacao);

        if (insertMovtoResult != true) {
            console.error("Erro ao realizar inserção de movto, iniciando rollback...")
            transaction.rollback()
            resolve(false)
            return 
        }

        transaction.commit((err: boolean) => {
            resolve(!err) //Retorna negação do erro ou seja se houve erro retorno false, se não houve retorna true
        });
    });
});
```

---

```
//dentro de uma função assincrona
var sucesso = await Banco.persistirPagamento(...);
if (sucesso) console.log('Operação realizada');
else console.log('Erro durante a transação');
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.